# dplyr -- tidyverse, pipes, correlation, same variable across time "a" "b"

Tags: statistics, r, data-visualization

Have a look at this dataset. The"a" and "b" are used to make possible differentiate when the *same* variable was measured. In this case X1a and X1b access the same variable, but "a" was (suppose..) in the last year and "b" was this year.

[image: Original dataframe]
I just want to correlate "a" and "b" and plot it. Simple like that and I really imagine the following code can be improved.

The final plot will be this one:
[image: Correlation plot]
The data is fake, but it's virtually equal as the original dataset I'm working on.

```
 all_items <- data.frame("1a" = sample(1:5), 
                            "2a" = sample(1:5),
                            "3a" = sample(1:5),
                            "1b" = sample(1:5),
                            "2b" = sample(1:5),
                            "3b" = rep(sample(1:5),10))


    #matrix with correlation
    all_correlation <- cor(all_items, method = "spearman") %>% 
      as.data.frame()

    #filter
    all_correlation <- all_correlation %>% select(-c(ends_with("a"))) #columns

    #create a colum with the now name
    all_correlation <- all_correlation %>% 
      mutate(item = row.names(.)) %>% select(item, everything())

    #supress some rows
    all_correlation <- all_correlation %>%  filter(!grepl("b", item))

    #filter(stringr::str_detect(row.names(.), "b"))
    #get only the diagonal
    all_correlation <- data.frame(item=1:3,Result=diag(as.matrix(all_correlation[, -1])))

    #P Value
    all_correlation_p_value <- Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(all_items))$P %>% as.data.frame()

    #filter
    all_correlation_p_value <- all_correlation_p_value %>% select(-c(ends_with("a")))
    all_correlation_p_value <- all_correlation_p_value %>% mutate(item = row.names(.)) %>% select(item, everything())
    all_correlation_p_value <- all_correlation_p_value %>%  filter(!grepl("b", item))
    all_correlation_p_value <- data.frame(item=1:3,P_Valor=diag(as.matrix(all_correlation_p_value[, -1])))

    #General table with the correlation  results
    all_correlation <- right_join(all_correlation,all_correlation_p_value, by = "item")


#Plot
ggplot(all_correlation, aes(x=item, y=Result)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Result)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("text", x = all_correlation$item, 
           y=all_correlation$Result, 
           label = paste("P-value =",round(all_correlation$P_Valor,3)), hjust = -0.1, colour = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,3,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible rewrites. For the first one, notice how `Hmisc::rcorr` already computes correlations (`$r`) and p-values (`$P`) matrices so you can base all your work from it, provided you extract the rights rows (`a_vars`) and columns (`b_vars`) and only keep the diagonal values:

```
correlations <- rcorr(as.matrix(all_items), type = "spearman")
a_vars <- ends_with("a", vars = names(all_items))
b_vars <- ends_with("b", vars = names(all_items))
all_correlation <- data.frame(
  item    = seq_along(a_vars),
  Result  = diag(correlations$r[a_vars, b_vars]),
  P_Valor = diag(correlations$P[a_vars, b_vars])
)
```

What I don't like too much about this approach is that it only uses 3 of the 36 correlations that were computed by `rcorr`. In this second approach, I start by splitting the data into two tables (one for `a` and one for `b`) so as to compute only 3 correlations via `Map`. I also switched from `rcorr` to the base `cor.test` which has (IMO) a more intuitive behavior: when given two vectors as input, it computes one correlation, not four.

```
a <- all_items %>% select(ends_with("a"))
b <- all_items %>% select(ends_with("b"))
cor_test <- Map(cor.test, a, b)
all_correlation <- data.frame(
  item    = seq_along(a),
  Result  = sapply(cor_test, `[[`, "estimate"),
  P_Valor = sapply(cor_test, `[[`, "p.value")
)
```

Comment: Wow!! Both are amazing solutions! Thanks much for replying my question. I will go with the first one because my knowledge of "sapply" still very incipient and (because of that) it is not easy to understand what sapply does. Thank you!